# Disable double underscore behaviour for Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel, pg, sequel-gem

How disable double underscore behaviour for Sequel?

I work with legacy data base schema where I have a lot of columns with "__" in name.

```
db[:abc].insert({vector_a__c: "356"})
Sequel::DatabaseError: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "vector_a" of relation "abc" does not exist
LINE 1: INSERT INTO "abc" ("vector_a"."c") VALUES ('356') RETURNING ...
```

Comment: Who creates a schema with double-underscores? You sure you can't just rename these tables?

Comment: You can't rename legacy tables or legacy apps accessing them will break.

Comment: I'd ask this on the Sequel IRC or mail lists. Jeremy Evans will be able to tell you exactly where to look.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general you want to wrap it in an identifier:

```
db[:abc].insert(Sequel.identifier(:vector_a__c) => "356")
```

Using a string as an identifier only works in very few cases for backwards compatibility, where it is unambiguous (i.e. where an SQL string would not be valid).

Answer (score 1):

Double underscore behavior disabling when you transfer columns names as string but not  as symbol.

For example:

```
db[:abc].insert({"vector_a__c" => "356"})
```